# Нужно синонимизировать метки [camera] и [камера]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Нужно синонимизировать метки:

- [camera](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/camera) (163 вопроса), есть описание.
- [камера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0) (52 вопроса), описания нет.

Основная - [камера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0), т. к. она на русском. А описание хорошо бы тоже перенести.

Comment: Как вы эти метки находите только?)

Comment: @Глеб  предполагаю, что при выпиливании меток, либо при просмотре главной страницы.

Comment: @Глеб, просто просматриваю список новых вопросов, и если вижу какую-то метку, у которой велика вероятность существования синонима на другом языке, и, если такой действительно есть, пишу на мету.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Готово!

```
updating post history, 169 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 163 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 158 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'camera': [camera] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records for type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 210
tag remapping of [камера] and [camera] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
1 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
24 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym camera -> камера was approved!
```